# How to change WooCommerce roles on login?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I am working on a wholesale site and want the site to automatically change the user roles to wholesale customer after login.

This will allow the customers to see wholesale pricing.

I have customized this code (below) and have added it in the Code Snippet plugin, but it doesn't seem to be working. Could anyone see what I'm missing?

```php
function uiwc_change_role()
{
    // get WP_user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // if the this is a registered user and this user is not an admin
    if (false !== $user && !user_can($user, 'administrator')) {

        //set the new role to our customer
        $user->set_role('wholesale-customer');
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'uiwc_change_role', 100, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the problem is related with the hook you have used but I have modified your code with "wp_footer" hook. I assume you already created an user role called "wholesale-customer".

```
function uiwc_change_role()
{
    // get WP_user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles;

    // if the this is a registered user and this user is not an admin
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !user_can($user, 'administrator') && !in_array('wholesale-customer', $role)) {

        //set the new role to our customer
        $user->set_role('wholesale-customer');
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'uiwc_change_role');
```

Tested and works. I hope this will help you. Have a good day.

Comment: I changed "wholesale-customer" to "wholesale_customer" because I'm using the WooCommerce Wholesale Prices plugin—and it worked!! Thank you SO much!! My only concern is this (a small detail): When the customer logs in, it takes them to the My Account page. On that page, the wholesale pricing is not showing up. It shows up when you go to the Shop page (and when you go back to the My Account page). But it doesn't show up initially, which might lead customers to think the prices are higher than they really are. Is there any way to customize the code so these results show up right after login?

Comment: I believe a little redirection will solve this issue. Can you update your question with your new code please?

Comment: Of course. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/kimhawleydesign/6f8825e9144a7374fe277a1436c47c6a